# no se como ingresar el valor que necesito para que realice el calculo

Tags: javascript

intento generar este calculo y me da error constante... como se debe ingresar./
El seguro que debo calcular es 0,20, no es un porcentaje, sino un numero decimal

```
var seguro = 0.20;
var segurodevida= (saldofinanciar * seguro) / 100;
```

Es Javascript... el resultado de saldofinanciar es 47500, tiene que multiplicarse por 0,20 /100 y como resultado tiene que dar 95... pero no da ningun resultado.

El calculo total que hago es el siguiente:

```js
var i = 47 / 1200;
var saldofinanciar = 47500;
var numeroCuotasrefi = 12;
   var Cuotapura = saldofinanciar / ((1 - Math.pow(i+1, -numeroCuotasrefi)) / i);
   //console.log(Cuotapura)  // debe dar 5036,39     
   //INTERES= monto a refinanciar por la TNA dividido 1200  debe dar 1860,42    // //
   var interescuotapura = saldofinanciar * (47 /1200);
   //console.log(interescuotapura)  
   //IVA= el interes por 21% dividido 100   debe dar 390,69
   var iva = 21;
   var ivarefi= (interescuotapura * iva) / 100;
   //console.log(ivarefi)
   //AMORTIZACIÓN = cuota pura menos interes  debe dar 3176,37
   var amortirefi= Cuotapura - interescuotapura;
   //console.log(amortirefi)
   //SEG. DE VIDA = 0,20 por monto a refinanciar para este saldo debe dar 95
   var seguro = 0.20;
   var segurodevida= (saldofinanciar * seguro) / 100;
   //console.log(segurodevida)
   //LA CUOTA FINAL ES= AMORTIZACION+INTERES+IVA+SEGDEVIDA
   var cuotafinalRefi = (interescuotapura + amortirefi + ivarefi + segurodevida).toFixed(2);
   console.log(cuotafinalRefi)
   // RESULTADO PRIMERA CUOTA TOTAL-. 
   //$('#importeCuotasrefi').val(cuotafinalRefi);
```

La cuota final debe dar $5522,47, solo tiene este valor 1 cuota, esto es el sistema de amortizacion frances... no necesito las cuotas siguientes, pero si que la primer cuota sea la correcta./ Yo hago esto en excel, los valores son los que comento en cada variable, solo para este caso en que el saldo a financiar es 47500

Comment: Deberías indicar, por lo menos, el **lenguaje de programación** que estás usando.

Comment: Error de constante tal vez quisiste decir, ademas usa la notación ```const```, en lugar de ```var```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: supongo que esto es javascript?

Comment: y que numero te esta dando?

Comment: Ahi edite tu publicacion... pone los valores que corresponde asi se puede probar.. y pone el valor que queres que salga...

Comment: ya lo resolvi... tenia mal ingresado un ;...  y el breackpoint lo hacia en ese lugar./ Gracias